# Cloud spanner: select count * takes over a minute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I created a test table in cloud spanner and populated it with 120 million rows. i have created a composite primary key for the table.

when i run a simple "select count(*) from " query, it takes approximately a minute for cloud spanner web UI to return results.

Is anyone else facing similar problem?

Comment: I'm not a database expert but, in SQL Server I have learned and switched my syntax in this case to use COUNT(1) rather than COUNT(*) as I had read somewhere that the * will cause the engine to resolve all the columns just as SELECT * does, and this will slow down the query similarly.

Answer (score 6):

Cloud Spanner does not materialize counts, so queries will like "select count(*) ...." will scan the entire table to return the count of rows, hence the higher time to execute.
If you require faster counts, recommend keeping a sharded counter updated transactionally with changes to the table.

Answer (score 1):

@samiz - you answer **"recommend keeping a sharded counter updated transactionally with changes to the table"**

how can we detect **how many sharded counter** need for the table? there is no retry n transaction...

thank you